# For the reader's convenience

Tags: saxon-genitive

Let's say that, for the reader's convenience, I want to repeat in Chapter 7 an equation that I stated in Chapter 2.

What is the correct way of saying "for the reader's convenience"?:

> a) For the reader's convenience
>
> b) For reader's convenience
>
> c) For reader convenience

Thank you.

Comment: I've seen both (_a_) and (_c_); in general, my experience has been that (_a_) is used as part of a complete sentence (e.g., _Equation 2.1 is here reproduced for the reader's convenience._), while (_c_) is more likely to be used in a parenthetical note (e.g., _(reproduced for reader convenience)_).

Comment: Another possibility could be, "Recall from Chapter 2 the following equation..."

Comment: I can also think of plural forms: *for readers' convenience* and *for the readers' convenience*.

Answer (score 1):

When wondering about questions like this, I consult:

- [google n-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20reader%27s%20convenience%2C%20for%20the%20reader%27s%20convenience%2C%20for%20reader%20convenience&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20reader%20%27s%20convenience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20the%20reader%20%27s%20convenience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20reader%20convenience%3B%2Cc0), which show that *for the reader's convenience* is by far the most common of the three expressions
- a large corpus

  - such as the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), where `reader 's convenience` (the space is there because of the way words are separated in the corpus) yields a single result, again in the phrase *for the reader's convenience*, while `reader convenience` yields two occurrences of *for reader convenience*
  - in the [iWeb Corpus](https://www.engrelish-corpora.org/iweb/), a search for `* * reader 's convenience` yields

    - 31 occurrences of *for the reader's convenience*
    - 1 occurrence of each of *as per reader's convenience*, *the present reader's convenience*, *the ordinary reader's convenience*, *provided for reader's convenience*, and *for your reader's convenience*

    while `* * reader convenience` gives

    - 11 occurrences of *added for reader convenience*
    - 9 occurrences of *as a reader convenience*
    - 3 occurrences of *provided for reader convenience* as well as *# For reader convenience* (where # is the beginning of a paragraph or something like that)
    - 2 occurrences of *. For reader convenience*, *are for reader convenience*, *category for reader convenience*, *included for reader convenience*, *pdf for reader convenience*, *settings for reader convenience*
    - 11 other phrases, each of which occurs just once

Based on this, I would go with `For the reader's convenience`.

Comment: This is a very interesting, practical and useful answer. Yet, I would like to know if there is any stylistic or grammatical rule that establishes the (most) correct use.